# Every subsequnce being Cauchy implies the entire net being Cauchy as well?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I was dealing with a specific problem but would like to consider a very general case.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{x_\alpha\}$ be a net in $X$. Here, $\alpha$ is (possibly uncountable) some infinite directed index set.

If every sub"sequence" I extract from this "net" $\{x_\alpha\}$ is Cauchy, can I conclude that this entire net $\{x_\alpha\}$ itself is Cauchy?

Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: Do you want to consider subsequences or subnets?

Comment: What is a $\mathbb{C}$-valued net in a space $X$?

Comment: Oops. I will make some corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $X$ is a metric space. The notion of Cauchy sequence or Cauchy net [2]  is not defined in a general topological space. It must be a uniform space [1].

We will prove the claim by establishing the contrapositive. If the net $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is not Cauchy, then   there exists $\epsilon>0$ with the following property:

(*) For each $\alpha \in A$, there   exist  $\gamma>\beta>\alpha$ in $A$ such that $d(x_\gamma,x_\beta) \ge \epsilon$.

Given $\alpha_1 \in A$, find corresponding $\gamma_1>\beta_1>\alpha_1$ as in $(*)$.  Let $\alpha_2:=\gamma_1$, and find corresponding $\gamma_2>\beta_2>\alpha_2$ as in $(*)$. Then define $\alpha_3=\gamma_2$, etc.

The sequence $\{x_{\alpha_i}\}_{i \ge 1}$ is not Cauchy.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Cauchy_net